# WPF remove grid layout child using name

Tags: wpf, layout, grid

Given a `Grid`, I'm adding a child to it using `Grid.Children.Add(element)`. How can I remove this element using its name? Something like `Grid.Children.Remove("name")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIElement child = grid1.FindName("name") as UIElement;
grid1.Children.Remove(child);
```